# Segmentation fault with strcpy() with array of pointers to structures

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcpy

Constants:

```
#define MAX_OPCODE_NAME_LEN 4
```

I have an array of structs:

```
OPCODE *mot[NUM_OPCODES];
```

Struct def:

```
typedef struct opcode {
char name[MAX_OPCODE_NAME_LEN + 1];
char format;
int type;
} OPCODE;
```

In my code:

```
strcpy(mot[0]->name, "hlt");
strcpy(mot[1]->name, "add");
strcpy(mot[2]->name, "sub"); // seg fault on this command
strcpy(mot[3]->name, "mul");
// ...more code follows
```

My code gives me a segmentation fault here and I'm not sure why, since it should have enough space to hold 5 characters (4 char followed by '\0'), so it shouldn't be running out of space, and I'm just copying a string literal into a static memory location. Perhaps I defined the struct incorrectly or used the pointer arrow in the wrong spot?

Comment: Did you allocate your array of pointers called `mot`?

Comment: I have it defined as `OPCODE *mot[NUM_OPCODES];` but that's all I did. Do i need to malloc something else for it?

Comment: That does not allocate any memory that the 4 pointers point to that you created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OPCODE *mot[NUM_OPCODES];
```

is an **array of pointers to `OPCODE`**. Not an **array of `OPCODE`s**.

You have either to allocate OPCODE memory for each pointer stored in mot or (easier way for the current code) just make mot an array of `OPCODE`s

```
OPCODE mot[NUM_OPCODES];
       ^^
```

and access the values as

```
strcpy(mot[0].name, "hlt");
strcpy(mot[1].name, "add");  ....
             ^^
```

Comment: `OPCODE mot[NUM_OPCODES];` and `strcpy(mot[0].name, "hlt");` worked, thanks.